# Pass a Table Column Name in a PostgreSQL Function

Tags: postgresql

I've read some posts about using table column names in a PostgreSQL function but I couldn't make it work for me.

I have this simple function

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.benchmark(CHARACTER VARYING, CHARACTER VARYING, BIGINT, BIGINT, BIGINT);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION benchmark(params CHARACTER VARYING, colName CHARACTER VARYING, idFrom BIGINT, idTo BIGINT, testNumber BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
    elemArray TEXT[] := ARRAY(SELECT colName FROM public.test WHERE test.id BETWEEN idFrom AND idTo);
    selectedElem RECORD;
    elem TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOREACH elem IN ARRAY elemArray LOOP
        raise notice 'elem Value: %', elem;
        SELECT elem INTO selectedElem;
        RETURN NEXT selectedElem;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I execute it with

```
SELECT * FROM public.benchmark('ad','name',1,2,1) AS x(Item TEXT);
```

I get

[image]

and what I should be getting are the **name** column values between **idFrom** and **idTo**. How can I use the colName variable as an actual column name in `elemArray TEXT[] := ARRAY(SELECT colName FROM public.test WHERE test.id BETWEEN idFrom AND idTo);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `RETURNS TABLE` + `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` for dynamic columns.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION benchmark(params CHARACTER VARYING, colName 
CHARACTER VARYING, idFrom BIGINT, idTo BIGINT, testNumber BIGINT) 
RETURNS TABLE (colvalue TEXT)  AS 
$$
 BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE --dynamic query
          format('SELECT %I::TEXT FROM test WHERE test.id BETWEEN $1 AND $2',colName)
                       --dynamic cols                           --bind parameters
   USING idFrom,idTo;
 END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3d1de905a23daf6c777b5f2dd486c099)

**EDIT**

> I just want to populate it with the elements of colName and use the
>   array later in the extended code

You could use `ARRAY_AGG` & load it into an array variable instead.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION benchmark(params CHARACTER VARYING, colName 
CHARACTER VARYING, idFrom BIGINT, idTo BIGINT, testNumber BIGINT) 
RETURNS void   AS 
$$
DECLARE
elemArray TEXT[];
    elem TEXT;
 BEGIN
 EXECUTE format('SELECT array_agg(%I::TEXT) FROM test 
                     WHERE test.id BETWEEN $1 AND $2',colName)
   USING idFrom,idTo INTO elemArray ;
   FOREACH elem IN ARRAY elemArray LOOP
    raise notice 'elem Value: %', elem;
    END LOOP;
 END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


knayak=# DO $$
knayak$# BEGIN
knayak$# PERFORM benchmark('ad','name',1,2,1);
knayak$# END
knayak$# $$;
NOTICE:  elem Value: TalG
NOTICE:  elem Value: John Doe
DO
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. In my minimal example I do return the elements in `elemArray` directly, but this code is going to be extended to to some other things with the `elemArray` so I don't need to return it. I just want to populate it with the elements of `colName` and use the array later in the extended code.

Comment: @TalG : Sure, The idea is same. Instead of  simple return query select column name, use `array_agg` and load it into an array variable. You should change the return type to whatever you want to return and also remove the return keyword in your actual example's query.

Comment: If doesen't cost you much effort could you please adjust your code to use this `array_agg` option, I'm new to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @TalG : Check Edits. Please always clearly mention what is required in the question to avoid multiple edits and clarifications.

Comment: Thank you very much and noted. One more thing, if I want to pass more than one one column name as a function parameter, then each of the e.g TEXT variables have to be wrapped using `array_agg(%I::TEXT)`? Is there a way to populate a record variable instead of just one array variable e.g (`elemArray`)?

Comment: @TalG "Format arguments according to a format string. This function is similar to the C function sprintf" C function `sprintf(...)` is not good to protect against SQL injections i doubt this PostgreSQL `Format(...)` function will be safe enough to prevent "all" SQL injections.. Best is to use `quote_ident()` and or `quote_literal()` to properly format your identifiers and literal in dynamic PostgreSQL queries

Comment: @RaymondNijland do you mean like this `EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || quote_ident(colName)|| ' FROM test WHERE test.id BETWEEN ' || quote_literal(idFrom) || ' AND ' || quote_literal(idTo) INTO elemArray;`? If I do this like this I get the error **ERROR: malformed array literal: "Tal" DETAIL: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.**

Comment: @Talg : You're welcome. I hope this answers your original question. You should consider asking a separate question(s) afresh with the details specific to one problem.

Comment: Something like that indeed @TalG  looks you have have forgotten the `array_agg(..)` function when using the methods i've said. And like 
Kaushik Nayak says if you try a comment on a answer and the method get bugs/errors you ideally should ask a other question.and maybe link to this question as reference and explain why you made a new question so you question will likely not be marked as a duplicated

Comment: @RaymondNijland you are right and everything works now with `EXECUTE 'SELECT array_agg(' || quote_ident(colName)|| ') FROM test WHERE test.id BETWEEN ' || quote_literal(idFrom) || ' AND ' || quote_literal(idTo) INTO elemArray;`. Thank you both.